# How to convert a JavaScript form to XML (or something else?)

Tags: javascript, xml, forms

I am working on a program that makes score forms in JavaScript. The form itself is fully functional (it calculates the scores just fine), but now I'm looking for a way to save these results to some sort of file that can also be loaded by the same program, both on the same system as on other systems and/ord devices.

I picked up that XML could be used in some way for this, but I have no idea where to start with this. The fields in the form are nothing special: a combination of text forms (some of whom have dynamically caluclated results, i.e. three fields have the numbers 8, 8 and 7 in them with the fourth having 23 in it) and a few drop-downs. This might change what code to use in this case, or maybe not.

So my question is as follows: how can I save and load the content of a JavaScript form to an easily movable file, and should I use XML for this or something else? Answers in either code, a short list of steps or link to a full-blown tutorial are all welcome.

Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: Is this client side or server side javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store files on the local user's machine with ease. Depending on the lifetime of the information you're storing, you can either use LocalStorage, Cookies or a server-side database system.

You can let the user select a file to upload/download which will be used for storage as a last resort if you wanted.

However, I'd advise that you store the data using [JSON](http://codular.com/json), as it is super simple to use, especially with JavaScript.

The best thing would be to have something run on a server (PHP or Node or other) which will then store the data for you.